# How to migrate from Apama 4 to Apama5.1?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, complex-event-processing, apama

I have CEP project built in Apama 4 and I am now migrating to Apama 5.1. But I am new to it and unable to figure out how to open even the old project. I went through the pdfs but not much help. Please someone guide me as to how to begin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are asking how to do this within your Eclipse environment (Apama studio)

```
Go to File -> Import -> Existing Projects into Workspace [Click next]
```

Select the root directory of the project, you will see the project name populating in the window below.

Click `Finish`